Should I submit my paper to another journal after long delays in publication?
In January 2024, I submitted my paper to the University of Michigan Undergraduate Research Journal (UMURJ). I received confirmation of acceptance for review in March 2024, and after some back and forth in May, I was sent a contract to fill out and sign, which I did (read it here). Following this, the editor sent me reviewer feedback on May 22, and I submitted the revised version of my paper by June 9, 2024.
However, since then, I've encountered significant delays. I last received a response from the editor in July, stating that my paper was well-received but the journal was undergoing leadership changes. I followed up twice in August and once in October but received no substantive updates. In the last response from the journal (dated August 31), I was told to list my paper as "in publication" on my CV but was given no timeline or further explanation.
I’m now uncertain about the future of my paper with UMURJ. Given the extended delays and lack of communication, I’m wondering if it would be acceptable (and legal) to submit my paper to another journal. I signed a contract with the journal, but there has been no clear progress or communication.
What are the best steps I can take here? Should I move on and submit elsewhere, or is there any potential issue with this due to the contract I signed? Would this action negatively affect my academic reputation?

(Note substantial modifications, based on the contract.) In general, before you submit to a new place you need to withdraw the paper from the old place. In this case, however, it is more complicated, since you signed a contract that is presumably binding on you.
Prior to signing a contract, you don't need their agreement to withdraw, but now you do. Depending on that contract one might not still hold copyright to the work, but things vary, and in your case, it seems you retain copyright having granted only a license. Moreover, your contract seems to grant them non-exclusive rights to publish. This implies that you can also publish elsewhere but that is up to any other publisher.
You can ask them to cancel the contract/license, and they might be willing to do so, but it is up to them, since you have signed it.
Note that some publishers want an exclusive right to publish and, perhaps, the copyright itself and won't publish things that have previously appeared. They seem to be loosening a bit on this and might in this case, but it is an issue to consider.
It is worth the ask. I suggest that you don't try to submit elsewhere until they discuss it with you and perhaps void the contract. This would make dealing with other publishers easier. If you do submit without such an agreement, note to that new potential publisher that there is an outstanding license held by UMURJ. If you handle it correctly there should be no negative consequences to your reputation.
Note that publishers can be very unhappy about dual/multiple submissions as it costs them time and effort that will be wasted. Contracts are more serious.
